# Converting xml attribute double quotes to single quotes (utility needed, pref java)

Tags: java, xml, quotes, castor

I have a seriously annoying problem. My company uses castor to marshall and unmarshall xml. I'm working on integrating with another company and it looks like their xml parser requires attributes to be single-quoted. Castor is hardcoded to use double quotes. Whoops!

Does anyone know of a utility (preferrably a java library) which can safely convert these quotes?

Simple regexps are not a preferred solution because it will become extremely complicated and buggy when trying to fix escaped double quotes and unescaped single quotes inside the attribute values themselves. Plus I'd rather not spend the time writing and debugging such a util if one already exists.

Thanks
Alastair

Comment: Ouchie. +1 for you. that's a nasty problem to have. I've had similar issues, but not this one. Really don't know how any simple way to solve it. I hate XML parsers and generators that don't actually follow the rules for XML. Sadly there's a fair number of them out there.  :-(

Comment: If their parser requires attributes to be single-quoted then it is not an XML parser. Please try to persuade them that they're missing the whole point (and all the benefits) of using XML if they aren't handling it in a conformant way. (Frankly, I'm amazed. I wouldn't be that surprised to see an amateur home-brew parser that only handled double quotes, since that's what most people use most of the time; but requiring single quotes is bizarre.)

Comment: Oh thank the maker! 

I do NOT have to solve this problem any more. Thankfully this was the nightmare candidate problem which I was working on solving while waiting on a support ticket. The good news, nothing to do with the quotes!

Bad news, if you're reading this hoping for an answer, sorry buddy, I didn't find one :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're going to find an off-the-shelf serializer that does this. My suggestion (if you can't persuade your business partner to adopt XML standards) would be to find an open-source serializer (e.g. the Saxon one) and customize it.